# ItemTemplateSelector syntax to bind to a parent in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind a command when using a bindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector and I cannot make it work.
for semplicity I have :

**MainPage**

```
<StackLayout
        x:Name="MyItems"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector = "{StaticResource MyItemSelector}"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
    </StackLayout>
```

**Template**

```
 <buttons:Button                        
          Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=MyItems}, Path=ParentContext.MyButtonCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

The above does not work and crashes.What is the syntax I need to use?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your `ParentContext` to `BindingContext` like:

```
<buttons:Button                        
      Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=MyItems}, Path=BindingContext .MyButtonCommand}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```